# Authorizing a webhook service for git pull

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, git

I have a Webhook (https://github.com/adnanh/webhook) configured as a service. When triggered it runs a bash script with does a few commands including a Git Pull.

I have configured my Ubuntu 20.04 system with a Git SSH key and when I am connected git pull works fine. However when it is triggered via the Webhook I'm getting a permissions issue:

```
   staging-1 webhook[167184]: git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
   staging-1 webhook[167184]: fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
   staging-1 webhook[167184]: Please make sure you have the correct access rights
```

How can I configure an SSH key for the user the webhook is executing as?

Comment: Which user has the ssh key?

Comment: It is my user account, 'luke'. Do I need to create an ssh key for the root user?

Comment: No, but you do need the user running the webhook service (which obviously _should not be root_) to have an ssh key it can use to check out your GitHub repo.

Comment: OK, how do I determine the user running the service? The service is currently configured in /etc/systemd/service/webhook.service with [Install] WantedBy=multi-user.target

Comment: It's whatever user you created and then specified in the systemd unit.